# Excel vsto Addin(x86 & x64 both) setup loaded successfully in Excel 2010, but failed to load in excel 2007

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007, installshield-le

I have created the .vsto ExcelAddin.exe for both configurations(32-bit and 64-bit),using installshield wizard 2015LE in win7(64-bit), both are loaded and working fine in excel 2010, but none of them are loading in excel 2007,and displays the load status as below from excel COM add-in panel.

[image]

And Registry entry for the same is as below,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it..the registry key for 32-bit office excel 2007 in 64 bit windows system is different,therefore I replaced the key from **[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\application name\Addins\add-in ID]** to **[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\ap‌​plication name\Addins\add-in ID]** during building the setup exe.

[this link helped a lot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2778964/addins-for-office-programs-may-be-registered-under-the-wow6432node)

Please see the following table for the correct registry location for the different combinations of 32-bit/64-bit versions of Office and Windows.[image]